# MySQL UPDATE from same table and SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table *ps_country_lang* with country translations, that are not properly translated. I would need to perform an UPDATE, to replace the content of *name* where *id_lang* equals 3 with the contents of *name* where *id_lang* equals 2 from the same *id_country*.

This is a small part of the table, so you can understand better:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|id_country |id_lang    |name           |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|27         |1          |Nueva Zelanda  |
|27         |2          |New Zealand    |
|27         |3          |Nueva Zelanda  |
|28         |1          |Corea del Sur  |
|28         |2          |South Korea    |
|28         |3          |Corea del Sur  |
|29         |1          |Israel         |
|29         |2          |Israel         |
|29         |3          |Israel         |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you include an example of what your desired result might look like, given the table you've supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update ps_country_lang dst
join ps_country_lang src on src.id_country = dst.id_country 
                        and src.id_lang = 2 
                        and dst.id_lang = 3
set dst.name = src.name
```